# How to bridge Bridge Spring and Camel property placeholders?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Application:-Springboot apache camel application

I have below kind of statement in my application properties:-

hm.integration.output=file://C:/cloud/out?fileName=${headers.CamelFileName}

But when I run this application, the application context fails to load because it treats ${headers.CamelFileName} as a Spring property as it starts with $. How can I avoid this situation?

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: See the alternative syntax in Simple, eg you can use `$simple{xxx}` at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/simple-language.adoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the alternative syntax in Simple, eg you can use `$simple{xxx}` at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/docs/simple-language.adoc

```
hm.integration.output=file://C:/cloud/out?fileName=$simple{headers.CamelFileName}
```

Comment: Have tested with your suggestion, Worked perfectly fine!
Thanks !!